# AWS public IPv4 address usage

Tags: amazon-web-services

Even though i have terminated all my instances, Amazon virtual private cloud shows billing for the usage of public ipv4 address..... How to stop the usage of this ip address?

I tried to delete subnet but it's not working.
And also it creates subnets in various regions, why so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit here. Did you try re:Post? Also, you have three questions in one (none of them is suited for SO thought) - it's better to separate them. Finally, it is impossible to answer the question "it's not working". You can learn this and a lot more in [help]

Comment: AWS provides a default VPC in each region. There is no charge for having a VPC and there is no charge for having subnets. You can certainly remove VPCs and Subnets you have created yourself, but I would recommend against deleting the default VPC and its Subnets otherwise services might not work when you attempt to launch them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Go to billing, check the region

Step 2: Go to that region, check Elastic IPs and Elastic network interfaces. If you see any public IPs, those are ones that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have used any `Elastic IP Addresses`? They are the one's that bring along charges when kept ideal.

Further reference - https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-billing-terminated

Comment: You are charged for all public IPv4 addresses now, not just idle Elastic IP addresses.

Comment: But  as per the question In this case the instances are already terminated, Hence the catch remains EIP's